# How to get the proper exit code from nohup

Tags: unix, nohup

From the nohup documentation in `info coreutils 'nohup invocation'` it states:

```
Exit status:

 125 if `nohup' itself fails, and `POSIXLY_CORRECT' is not set
 126 if COMMAND is found but cannot be invoked
 127 if COMMAND cannot be found
 the exit status of COMMAND otherwise
```

However, the only exit codes I've ever gotten from nohup have been 1 and 0. I have a nohup command that's failing from within a script, and I need the exception appropriately...and based on this documentation I would assume that the nohup exit code *should* be 126. Instead, it is 0.

The command I'm running is: `nohup perl myscript.pl &`

Is this because perl is exiting successfully?

Comment: try much simpler tests to see if nohup is giving the documented values. `nohup true; echo $?`, `nohup false; echo $?`, `nohup nonesuch; echo $?`, from the unix command-line should give you some working feedback. Good luck.

Comment: What's the exit code if you run `perl myscript.pl` under the same configuration (environment, etc.)?  If your script exits with 0, then perl will exit with 0.  Perl will pass along your script's exit code.  Perl itself will exit with various errors if it can't run the script (e.g. 13 for invalid permissions on the file).

Comment: This question really belongs on Super User.

Comment: well, based on some suggestions here, I've figured out that the reason why this is happening is that nohup is being run as a subprocess (with &). When I don't call it with &, I get the correct exit code (127). Called with & I get 0. Is there any way to still get the correct exit code and use & ?

Comment: This is about shell programming; SO is for questions about programming; this question fits very happily here on SO.

Comment: You're right of course.  And you caught the `&` that I glossed over.  Good answer.

Comment: Do you know what an [1]+ Exit 3 message mean? Nowhere I can find the description for Exit 3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your shell script runs the process with:

```
nohup perl myscript.pl &
```

you more or less forego the chance to collect the exit status from `nohup`.  The command as a whole succeeds with 0 if the shell forked and fails with 1 if the shell fails to fork.  In `bash`, you can wait for the background process to die and collect its status via `wait`:

```
nohup perl myscript.pl &
oldpid=$!
...do something else or this whole rigmarole is pointless...
wait $oldpid
echo $?
```

The echoed `$?` is usually the exit status of the specified PID (unless the specified PID had already died and been waited for).

If you run the process synchronously, you can detect the different exit statuses:

```
(
nohup perl myscript.pl
echo "PID $! exited with status $?" >&2
) &
```

And now you should be able to spot the different exit statuses from `nohup` (eg try different misspellings: `nohup pearl myscript.pl`, etc).

Note that the sub-shell as a whole is run in the background, but the `nohup` is run synchronously within the sub-shell.

Comment: @arganzheng: It will wait until the background process (`nohup perl myscript.pl` in the example), terminates.  When I run the following code in Bash, it behaves as I'd expect, terminating after about 5 seconds: `sleep 5 &
oldpid=$!;
echo oldpid=$!;
sleep 3;
echo Awake;
wait $oldpid;
echo $?`  For example, it produced: `oldpid=40222`, then `Awake` and finally `0`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what does ...do something else or this whole rigmarole is pointless... means here? Can i use the code as it is without the ...do somthing part?

Comment: `nohup sleep 10 && (exit 1); echo "exited with status $?" &` seems to work for me

Comment: @PrashantKalkar: What result do you get?  I got `exited with status 1` after a 10 second snooze, which is what I expected.  But I'm not clear how that relates to what's discussed in the Q&A.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry I was not trying to answer the question in the comments. Just wanted to share what worked for me when running the process in background while still capturing the exit code.

Answer (score 3):

As my understanding, the question was how to get the command status when it was running in nohup. As my experiences it was very little chance that you were able to get the COMMAND exit status even when it failed right away. Most time you just got the 'nohup COMMAND &' exit status unless you wait or synchronize as Jonathan mentioned. To check the COMMAND status right after nohup, I use:

```
 
  pid=`ps -eo pid,cmd | awk '/COMMAND/ {print $1}'`
  if [ -z $pid ]; then
     echo "the COMMAND failed"
  else
     echo "the COMMAND is running in nohup"
  fi
```